# Duduplicate CSV File by Grouping with Element and Filtering by another

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, duplicates, php-7

Please a have some days trying to resolve a code To duduplicate csv file

the idea is to browse the csv file, remove duplicates and let the line that has the maximum id

For Example this file [CSV FILE TO duduplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoZro.png)

And the result will be [rewriting of result into csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpsJ1.png)

```
while (($this->lineInWork = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
        if ($index == 0) {
            if (!$this->checkHeaderFile()) {
                fclose($handle);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $idProject    = $this->columns[self::ID_PROJET]['index'];
            $TitleProject = $this->columns[self::Title_Project]['index'];
            $currentTitle = null;
            if ($this->lineInWork[$TitleProject] != $currentTitle)
            {
                $currentTitle = $this->lineInWork[$TitleProject];
                array_push($this->temporary_file[$currentTitle], $this->lineInWork);
            }
        }
        $index++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

The problem is not to rewrite file but is to build an array with the right lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do two different sorts for this (assuming I have understood what you are requiring). I have created  a quick csv writer, which you may already have:

```
protected function saveToCsv($data, $path)
{
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');

    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Script to filter and sort:

```
# Create a storage array
$new    =   [];
# Increment array to determine header row
$i      =   0;
# Turn the csv file to array
$array  =   array_map('str_getcsv', file('original.csv'));
# Sort low to high by the ID_project
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return ($a[0] < $b[0]);
});
# Loop the array and just re-assign over the top of each instance of value
# which will eventually assign the last value (highest)
foreach($array as $row) {
    if($i == 0) {
        # Save header to put back into the copy csv
        $header =   $row;
        $i++;
        continue;
    }
    # Assign by id so the values are unique and sortable after
    if(!isset($new[$row[2]]))
        $new[$row[2]]   =   $row;
}
# Resort by the app_id
ksort($new);
# Save the new CSV somewhere with the header merged
$this->saveToCsv(array_merge([$header], $new), 'copy.csv');
```